# Enhance sound of a Video recorded by CamStudio

Tags: audio, video, codec, virtualdub, camstudio

Ok, so I am trying to use CamStudio for my own youtube channel. I am new to this video codec thing, but I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQ5_6szOf48#t=1484) completely.

I am now testing it in full 1080p resolution. I used Xvid codec to encode my video. The video quality was good, but the audio was too low. I changed it to 44.1KHz Stereo and mono (PCM)both, but the sound was still low. However mono sound was lower than Stereo.

When I enhanced the sound to 200% in VLC, I was almost able to hear it correctly. But I couldn't ask my viewers to download the video and use VLC to play it.

I tried using virtualDB after seeing [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/13884/how-to-increase-the-volume-for-an-avi-file). But it converted my 7 MB AVI video to a massive 3.52 GB AVI. I enhanced the sound to maximum (+30dB just for testing it). The sound was good, except some background noise, but I can live with that. My only concern is with the file size.

I am guessing that the output codec used by virtualDB was the default one and not XVid (I took reference from the CamStudio video tutorial about codecs). I also guessed this because virtualDB didn't let me use `Direct stream copy` in video and I had to use `Full Processing mode`. It gave me a warning about codec when playing the output file.

```
The currently selected output plugin cannot be used in direct stream copy mode.
```

Any idea how to make it work in Direct stream copy mode?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found an answer just by trying out. I am not able to play the output video still, when I am in direct stream mode for video. But I can just hit save and it'll save the audio enhanced video. This way the file size was almost similar (upped by few KBs). I guess I can live with that. Leaving the question in case it help someone.