# A Media Player that increases the sound volume?

Tags: windows-7, audio, media, media-player

I have some movies that they have low sound volume , thus I'm looking for a Media Player that increase the sound volume by itself.
Would be OK if you introduced me the Media Player that could do it? ;)

BTW : I have win 7 x64

Comment: A few similar/duplicate questions to look at: http://superuser.com/questions/13552/how-to-amplify-the-audio-in-a-video-file . http://superuser.com/questions/13884/how-to-increase-the-volume-for-an-avi-file .

Comment: Well, You're right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc) increases the sound of the video up to 200%

Comment: Can't we do it with Windows Media Player?

Comment: no,windows media player doesn't do that

Comment: BTW: As I realized; we can increase the volume sound with VLC up to 400%. Use middle button of the mouse and roll it.

Comment: yeah,it does that as well,but I guess that decreases the quality of the audio

Comment: WMP is lame (not the mp3 encoder!). A quick comment by yours truly; you need to realize that the M$ junk really is just gimmick software. Once you get to know the computer you realize that you can get along just fine if not better without the M$ junk! Anyways basically use VLC!

Comment: @Phobia: anytime you amplify the sound volume in software, you run the risk of overload (aka *clipping*), which is pretty solidly a decrease in quality.  the better-quality option is to hook up your audio to some external amplifier and turn up the volume there.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a Plugin for Windows Media Player for increasing sound volume.
[DFX Audio Enhancement](http://www.fxsound.com/dfx/pages/overview/index.php?vendor=0&subvendor=0&plus=0&refer=0)
It sounds better than VLC ;)