# Can I increase the sound volume in my computer (Windows 7) beyond the volume control?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Can I increase the sound volume in my computer beyond the volume control without additional hardware or speakers?

In Windows, I feel many video files sound very low even after increasing the volume to the highest level. Why is that?

Is there any software that can increase volume level? [I use Media Player](https://superuser.com/questions/144081/no-suitable-decoder-module-vlc-does-not-support-the-audio-or-video-format-undf) classic ([because many videos do not work on VLC](https://superuser.com/questions/120273/a-media-player-that-increases-the-sound-volume)) to see videos.

Answer (score 5):

I find it very hard to believe that VLC plays less formats than WMPC does... Very very hard. What kind of video's are we talking about here? Since VLC DOES allow you to exceed the 100% volume setting, this would be my recommended solution for you. When its volume bar is filled half way, it's at 100% volume, that means you can set it up to 200% volume from VLC.

**UPDATE:**

Besides VLC you could also check out http://www.fxsound.com/dfx/pages/overview/index.php?vendor=0&subvendor=0&plus=0&refer=0

Comment: I know sound can be increase in VLC .see here http://superuser.com/questions/144081/no-suitable-decoder-module-vlc-does-not-support-the-audio-or-video-format-undf

Comment: Check my update

Answer (score 1):

If it's video files you're referring to, such as AVI files, then get the AC3 Filter codec and change the settings. You can change the volume gains of video files to your liking, even if you have surround sound, change the gains per speaker.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use VLC audio volume increase for media files, but I'm trying to increase the volume on the YouTube Coachella stream with the Flash plugin and my speakers already up to max. This is how I did it in Windows 7:

1. Right click on "speak icon" on the right corner of the display
2. Click "Playback devices"
3. Under Playback Tab, click "Speaker -HD Audio Device" and then click "Properties"
4. Under Enhancements Tab, check on "Loudness Equalization", then click OK

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to show up late into the thread, hopefully this will help others (as it did help me):

I've found [Letasoft Sound Booster](http://www.letasoft.com/) that apparently performs some leveling (?) on the audio stream that goes to soundcard (this means it might get applied on the master volume, not individual apps).
The effect was quite impressive when I tried to listen to a live cast that had a very low sound volume (despite the fact that my laptop has quite loud speakers).

The only downside is that is not free and is buggy (it crashed every two-three minutes the entire google chrome process while in firefox it crashed adobe flash player plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The software included with your sound card (whether it be integrated or discrete) may have an additional volume control. Additionally, some codecs have a separate volume control. I know I have to mess with that option every time I download the acc audio codec.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the speaker then go to "playback devices".

Hit speakers and select "properties".

Go to "advances" and change default quality to the highest.

Click "apply" and it is done.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Even googling I see nothing about "default quality". There is a volume control within right click speaker icon..playback devices..speakers..properties.. but it reflects the volume set at the volume control.